# Disable browser redirect to app store

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-1020

There is a website that I'd like to access via the web browser but I keep getting redirected to the app store. They have a native app but I don't want to use it because it's buggy, etc.

How can I disable automatic redirection from a website to the app store?

Comment: Can you add a link to the website in question?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to disable the store redirection in the browser. You will need to ask the website owner to disable the redirect or to let you opt out.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a 3rd party browser such as [Surfy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/surfy-browser/9wzdncrfhvrf), [Opera Mini](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/opera-mini/9wzdncrdmtk6), [UC browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/UC-BrowserHD/9WZDNCRFJ3KN), etc... you can access the site without redirection to Store.

What Thomas [said](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12696/18061),

> There is no way to disable the store redirection in the browser.

is true when one is using Internet Explorer/Edge.

This also hold good for some other redirections. For example you can access Bing website from a 3rd party browser but you will be redirected to Search app on Internet Explorer.

The reason this redirection happens is because these websites are designed to redirect to Windows store if the device is a Windows Phone. Using a 3rd party browser can get you around this restriction by not revealing the name of your OS.

If problem persists try using **Speed mode** in UC browser or similar mode in other browsers. This option will redirect the traffic via their servers for compression and the websites will read the OS of the server, thus allowing you to view their webpage.

Comment: I've tried using both Surfy and Opera Mini and they still redirected me to the app store... Any ideas why?

Comment: @NateW Have you tried enabling Speed mode /Turbo mode on Surfy?

Comment: @NateW Updated my answer with additional info on how this works.

Comment: I tried using speed/turbo mode but they don't seem to work... I'm trying to access a https site. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @NateW I don't know for sure. Maybe. Can you mention the website you are accessing in your question, if that is not a problem to you.